# Including navigation bar in navigation

Tags: ios, animation

I am creating an animation where the current view controller slides down, revealing the new view controller beneath it. I have got this working with the view, but I would like to include the navigation controller in the view sliding down. So instead of a view sliding down with no navigation bar, It would slide down with the navigation bar at the top. How woould I fix this. Here is how I am doing it with the view:

```
- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    return 5.00;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIViewController* toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController* fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    [[transitionContext containerView] addSubview:fromViewController.view];
    toViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
        fromViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 2000, 320, fromViewController.view.frame.size.height);
        toViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, fromViewController.view.frame.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        fromViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];

    }];

}
```